# WSL2 is not handling file permissions properly, unable to write files from PHP

Tags: permissions, php, nginx, wsl2

I am running nginx, mariadb and php8.2-fpm on my WSL2 Ubuntu server successfully, all running as user `www-data` just fine, however, I cannot upload files from the web interface.  When I attempt to, the nginx error log records the following:

> 2023/05/03 09:27:46 [error] 1339#1339: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
> message: Uncaught PHP Exception
> Drupal\Core\File\Exception\FileWriteException: "The destination
> directory 'public://2023-05' is not writable" at
> /var/www/html/repo/web/core/modules/media_library/src/Form/FileUploadForm.php
> line 332" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1,
> server: localhost, request: "POST
> /media-library?media_library_opener_id=media_library.opener.field_widget&media_library_allowed_types%5Bimage%5D=image&media_library_selected_type=image&media_library_remaining=1&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_widget_id%5D=field_image&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bentity_type_id%5D=node&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bbundle%5D=article&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_name%5D=field_image&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bentity_id%5D=144&media_library_opener_parameters%5Brevision_id%5D=741&hash=q_RtKmTw2wyucMR1nnKCucBF2P1b1crtsxJDMyk7fW8&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax
> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:",
> host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"

Thinking that the issue may be with nginx and php8.2-fpm, I've also successfully configured apache to run with php8.2 and similarly get this error inside of Apache's error log:

> [Wed May 03 09:28:32.068299 2023] [php:notice] [pid 1195] [client
> ::1:59860] Uncaught PHP Exception
> Drupal\Core\File\Exception\FileWriteException: "The destination
> directory 'public://2023-05' is not writable" at
> /var/www/html/repo/web/core/modules/media_library/src/Form/FileUploadForm.php
> line 332, referer: http://localhost:8080/

nginx, mariadb and php-fpm are all running as `www-data` and the folder permissions are all set to `www-data:www-data` (`chown -R www-data:www-data ./`) with full access to the files (`chmod -R 777 ./`).

I've also added the following to my `/etc/wsl.conf` file:

```
[automount]
enable = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
mountFsTab = false
```

PHP is still unable to write to write files.  Any ideas on how to deal with write permissions on WSL 2 instances of Ubuntu?

Comment: So it's complaining about a directory called `public://2023-05`? It appears despite your best efforts the directory being used by `FileUploadForm.php` does not have the correct permissions. Provide the relevant information for your Drupal installation.

Answer (score -1):

The Drupal post
[The directory sites/default/files exists but is not writable and could not be made writable](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90586/the-directory-sites-default-files-exists-but-is-not-writable-and-could-not-be-ma)
might be relevant here.

The
[answer by Ankit Agrawal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/90592)
says this:

> One way that may work for you is changing the group and make it group
> writable as below:
>
> ```
> chgrp www-data sites/default/files
> chmod g+w sites/default/files
> ```
>
> As per [drupal docs](https://drupal.org/node/244924) the correct permission for all files is 644, and for directories is 755.
>
> Also check this: [What are the recommended directory permissions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions)

Replace `sites/default/files` with your folder.

Comment: Thanks harrymc, I unsuccessfully applied your recommendation, but I don't think it really changed anything.
I am running nginx and php8.2-fpm , both, as www-data , and all of my folders have www-data:www-data as user/group owners. (UID: 1000) .  I have also added www-data into my personal user group, as well as adding my personal user id into the www-data group.  Finally, I have given www-data:www-data 7777 ownership (chown) to the entire web directory, recursively.
This is Ubuntu running under WSL2 (Windows 11) , Composer is able to run and download files,

Comment: Reading docs link in my answer and its comments, it seems like the permissions need to be very exact. Try it.